# How can count and then order by the # of entries assigned to a category; and then limit to only the top 3?

Tags: templating

**How can I modify this to orderBy the # of entries and then limit to the top 3? **

```
{% for categoryName in craft.categories.group('markets') %}
    {% set numofEntries = craft.entries.section('posts').relatedTo(categoryName).total() %}

    <a href="{{ categoryName.url }}">{{ categoryName.title }} <sup>({{numofEntries}})</sup> </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd do this from a custom plugin so you could write some queries directly against the database.

If you're looking to do this from a template, this should work, albeit it's not very efficient.

```
{% set entryArr = {} %}

{# Store the slug as the key in an array and the total number as the value #}
{% for categoryName in craft.categories.group('markets') %}
    {% set entryArr = entryArr|merge({(categoryName.slug): craft.entries.section('posts').relatedTo(categoryName).total()}) %}
{% endfor %}

{# Sort the array by the descending value maintaining the keys #}
{% set entryArr = entryArr|sort|reverse %}

{# Grab the first 3 values from the array #}
{% set entryArr = entryArr|slice(0, 3) %}

{# print them off #}
{% for slug, number in entryArr %}
    {% set categoryName = craft.categories.slug(slug).one() %}
    {{ categoryName.title }} - ({{number}})
{% endfor %}
```